# Help deciphering this Japanese artist's signature

Tags: kanji, names

I know this is a long shot but I came across this Japanese artist's signature and I was wondering if anyone could help.
[image: signature]

Unfortunately I do not know the full name of the artist. The rightmost character is clearly 敏. The roman letter part seems to spell "Bando" or "I. Zando" or perhaps "I.Z. ando". The middle character is the most interesting to me. It's clear that the leftmost part of the character is the radical 玄, but I could not find any kanji with 玄 in this position. The middle part looks like a mirrored 了 and the rightmost part looks like some sort of dotted ま.

If anyone has any clues for understanding this signature, they would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly 敏雄? There is a [Wikipeadia article (linked to French one)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshio_Bando).

Comment: Yes this is it, thank you! I should have simply looked for "bando japanese artist" on google. What is your interpretation of the middle character with the 玄 radical? It does not look like 雄 to me.

Comment: I think ナ and ム are written consecutively without  'detaching' the brush from the canvas(?), resulting in the stroke in between and the whole thing looking like 玄.

Comment: Thanks! now i can also see the remainder as a stylized version of 隹.